# fplot error using second order derivatives / second-order differentiator circuit

Tags: matlab, dsolve

d2/dt2*i(t) + 25*d/dt*i(t) + 100*i(t) = 300

I want to plot x:time, y:i(t) graph using that second-derivative equation
Also I using matlab

```
syms i(t)
eq = diff(i(t),t,2) + 25*diff(i(t),t) + 100*i(t) == 300;
condition = i(0) == 0 ;

sol(t) = dsolve(eq, condition) ; 
fplot(sol, [0,5]);

xlabel('Time (s)'); ylabel('i(t)');
```

However, the error comes out like this.
Error using fplot>singleFplot (line 240)
Input must be a function or functions of a single variable.

```
Error in fplot>@(f)singleFplot(cax,{f},limits,extraOpts,args) (line 200)
        hObj = cellfun(@(f)
        singleFplot(cax,{f},limits,extraOpts,args),fn{1},'UniformOutput',false);

Error in fplot>vectorizeFplot (line 200)
        hObj = cellfun(@(f)
        singleFplot(cax,{f},limits,extraOpts,args),fn{1},'UniformOutput',false);

Error in fplot (line 166)
hObj = vectorizeFplot(cax,fn,limits,extraOpts,args);

Error in test (line 6)
fplot(sol, [0,5]);`
```

Do you know how to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself.
The condition has to be two, not one